# Advantages of vb.net over vb6 for CRUD application development

Tags: vb.net, vb6, crud

What are the improvements in vb.net compared to vb6 that make developing such an application easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a few:

- ADO.NET is better than ADO for data access (and more options such as the Entity Framework, data repository blocks, LINqtoSQL)
- better ability to structure your code for ease of maintenance because of better support for object oriented programming
- better testability
- overall a much better IDE
- better handling of XML
- richer set of interface choices: silverlight, WPF, WinForms, WebForms, ASP.NET MVC, 
  Web Client Software Factory
- ASP.NET allows you to divide your interface code from your business logic much better by moving the logic into the code-behind file: better separation of concerns leades to easier and cheaper maintenance costs
- WinForms has a much richer set of controls allowing you to build apps that are much easier for your users
- better integration wilth other Microsoft products such as Sharepoint

This is by no means an exhaustive list.  But it's at least a good starting point.

Comment: pretty comprehensive set of reasons all the same

Answer (score 1):

I switched to VB.Net because of LINQ. Everything else was a nice bonus. ^^

Answer (score 0):

The ability to use the farking scroll wheel on my mouse in the IDE!

Sorry, had to vent on that one since I've recently been stuck in VB6 for maintenance on a legacy app.

Comment: Kris: You are my hero for this week. I just wish I could upvote you some rep for that comment!